# How to use apscheduler to trigger job every minute between specific times?

Tags: python-3.6, apscheduler

I'm using python apscheduler module. Is it possible to trigger a job every minute between 7:30 AM and 11:30 PM every day?

I've tried following solution, but I don't know how to add constraint with minutes.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def job_function():
    print("Hello World")

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', hour='7-23', minute='*')

sched.start()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the new `OrTrigger` to combine several `CronTrigger`s to cover the whole time span:

```
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import OrTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

trigger = OrTrigger([
   CronTrigger(hour='7', minute='30-59'),
   CronTrigger(hour='8-22', minute='*'),
   CronTrigger(hour='23', minute='0-30')
])

sched.add_job(job_function, trigger)
```